# Using Recurrent Neural Network to solve Time Series task

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, time-series, recurrent-neural-network

I have the next problem to solve: Predict the "demand of job" for the next day/week.
I have samples for the last year (377 samples, 1 per day).
My variables are information related (or at least I think it's related): Day, Week, Month, Holiday, Weather conditions (temp, rain, snow), Subscriptions amount (13 variables)
I drew the demand of all the samples from the beginning until today and I got:

[image]

If I split this demand over the week (monday, tuesday, ...) I get:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I think this is a "Time series" problem so I am trying to solve it with Neural Networks and in particular with Recurrent Neural Networks.
My questions are the next:

1) Is it really a "Time series" problem?

2) Is it a good problem to be solved with NN? Which type? RNN?

3) If RNN is the best, should I consider another variable that maybe is common and I am not taking it into account?

4) If neural networks is not the best approach, which one is?

5) Should I try to train 7 different networks (one per day of the week) or should I try to train 1 "big" network?

6) Is it okay to keep the outliers or should I remove it? (outleirs occurs on holidays)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) Is it really a "Time series" problem?

By [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series), a time series is a series of data points indexed in time order. Your problem fits perfectly. So, yes, it is a time series problem.

> 2) Is it a good problem to be solved with NN? Which type? RNN?

RNN is certainly a candidate for this problem: RNNs are good at capturing similar patterns in the series data, like, for instance, learning language rules from large amount of sentences in the corpus. Your first chart clearly indicates that there's a dependency between points at consecutive time steps.

> 3) If RNN is the best, should I consider another variable that maybe is common and I am not taking it into account?

There's no universal answer to this question. Deep networks *can* learn new features from the input ones (it's called [*feature extraction*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_extraction)), but may also fail to do so, and you'll have to prepare them.

> 4) If neural networks is not the best approach, which one is?

Once again, this question is too broad. There is no single best approach. That's why I'm careful with formulation here: RNN is a good *candidate*, in other words, I can't see any problems with trying it right away.

There are books written on time series analysis, the statistical arsenal includes auto-regression, auto-correlation, seasonality, etc. And discussing those is totally out of scope of StackOverflow. If you're interested, I'd suggest you ask at [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com).

> 5) Should I try to train 7 different networks (one per day of the week) or should I try to train 1 "big" network?

You can do that if there's clear diversity in distributions between different days. Frankly, I didn't notice that in your charts above, but one needs to investigate the raw data to answer this question.

> 6) Is it okay to keep the outliers or should I remove it? (outleirs occurs on holidays)

In general, neural networks aren't good at predicting outliers, because there's no pattern here. But your very first chart doesn't show clear outliers, so it's an argument to work with it, rather than with per weekday charts.

Answer (score 0):

1. Can't say. Seems to be.
   2, 4. Yes, RNN are used to time series prediction.
2. Not sure about splitting by days. But probably you had some reason to do it.
3. I suppose, training 7 different networks is much harder than one.
4. Remove them and replace with the verage of nearest points. In all tasks that I worked on RNN are hardly solve outlier problems. Because of scaling (but probably RobustScaler may help if you won't remove them).